# discard newline character

Tags: matlab, newline, fopen, fgets

Here is the code that I am using;

```
files2 = dir('X_*.txt');

for kty=1:p

fidF = fopen(['X(A)_' num2str(kty) '.txt'], 'w');

for i = 1:length(files2)

fid = fopen(files2(i).name);

while(~feof(fid))

  string = fgetl(fid) 

 fprintf(fidF, '%s', string)


end

    fclose(fidF);
end

end
```

`P` equal to 90, because there have 90 different `X` text file which include different angles.The new `X(A)` text files should be 90 different files.

The code is used for getting rid of this second line and `it's working.`

The thing I want to ask is that when I use this code it creates `X(A)` text files (90 files) but all include `X_1` files angle variable but it should be;

```
X_1    >   X(A)_1        (each variable should transfer to new file.)
                                                 (X_65  > X(A)_65)
X_2    >   X(A)_2         
...
...
```

How can I fix the code?

```
  files2 = dir('angle_*.txt');

for i = 1:length(files2)
   fidF = fopen(['angle(A)_' num2str(i) '.txt'], 'w');
   fid = fopen(files2(i).name);
   while(~feof(fid))
      string = fgetl(fid) 
      fprintf(fidF, '%s', string)
   end
   fclose(fidF);
   fclose(fid);
end
```

result are

```
angle_1=272       angle(A)_1=272
angle_2=276       angle(A)_2=308
angle_3=280       angle(A)_3=312
angle_4=284       angle(A)_4=316
angle_5=288       angle(A)_5=320
angle_6=292       angle(A)_6=324
angle_7=296       angle(A)_7=328
angle_8=300       angle(A)_8=332
angle_9=304       angle(A)_9=336
angle_10=308      angle(A)_10=340
angle_11=312      angle(A)_11=344
angle_12=316      angle(A)_12=348

angle_10 variable goes to angle(A)_2 variable and its copy in this order.
```

Comment: I have no clue what you're saying. Please un-accept my answer so someone else can help you.

Comment: @Beaker, for example, look at your codes first line ,it read all the file (i have 90 files) and look at third line, its open new text files. All old files variable should be in transfer in order.  could you send me your email then I can send you images to explain.

Comment: You can add a link to an image in your question.

Comment: @ Beaker, do you understand it? I mean angle_6 and angle(A)_6 variables should be same, also another variables in another files should be same as old file such as angle_2 variable should be same as angle(A)_2 variable. But by using your code this variables are swap like angle_6 variable copying into angle(A)_2 variable. Thats the problem

Comment: Try printing out the first few file names in `files2` and see what order they're in.

Comment: (angle_1=272       angle(A)_1=272)              
(angle_2=276       angle(A)_2=308)
(angle_3=280       angle(A)_3=312)
(angle_4=284       angle(A)_4=316)
(angle_5=288       angle(A)_5=320)
(angle_6=292       angle(A)_6=324)
(angle_7=296       angle(A)_7=328)
(angle_8=300       angle(A)_8=332)
(angle_9=304       angle(A)_9=336)
(angle_10=308      angle(A)_10=340)
(angle_11=312      angle(A)_11=344)
(angle_12=316      angle(A)_12=348)

angle_10 variable goes to angle(A)_2 variable and its copy in this order. angle 11 variable is goes to angle(A)_3 variable.How can fix it.@Beaker

Comment: Ew... add it to the question... formatting in the comments is horrible.

Comment: @AsenMartin @beaker meant print out the **file names** not their contents. Use `files = dir('X_*.txt'); fprintf('%s\n', files.name)`.

Comment: I tried but it says I need 10 reputation point to send more than 2 image.

Comment: What are you pasting images for? Paste the text into the question and correctly format it!

Comment: the first are ok ,both of them 272 but then second column should be same as first column.

Comment: @AsenMartin Paste the output of the code in my comment into your question please.

Comment: @AsenMartin Astoundingly, I think this actually makes sense. Give me a few minutes.

Comment: @AsenMartin Have a look at my updated answer. Hopefully this will put things in the right order.

Comment: can we say; if n<10   , string='0'+num2str(n)    ,if n<100 and n>10    string='0'+num2str(n)    to fix the problem. @beaker

Comment: @AsenMartin Yes, you could do that. You'd have to do `string = ['0' num2str(n)]` to concatenate the strings. The updated regexp in my answer should also work for you and it doesn't rely on the numbers being consecutive.

Comment: Its working now.Thanks a lot @beaker

Comment: thanks a lot @IKavanagh

Comment: https://33.media.tumblr.com/6218d375d4a0b76acb439fe076854eaf/tumblr_ndknvp4FHy1sk0xezo1_500.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have your input and output files match, you need to remove one of the `for` loops and have `X(A)_#.txt` match `files2(#).name`:

```
files2 = dir('X_*.txt');

for i = 1:length(files2)
   fid = fopen(files2(i).name);
   fNum = regexp(files2(i).name, '([0-9]*)', 'match');
   fidF = fopen(['X(A)_' fNum{1} '.txt'], 'w');
   while(~feof(fid))
      string = fgetl(fid) 
      fprintf(fidF, '%s', string)
   end
   fclose(fidF);
   fclose(fid);
end
```

I've removed the loop from `1:p` and used the loop over the number of input files with `i` as the loop variable. `i` is used for both the output file name and the index to the input file list.

Comment: Thank you Beaker, My code is working to avoid empty lines but the thing i want to ask is that I have 90 files and when I use this code the files get rid of the second lines.The tricky part is how can I create 90 new text files and paste the variables in it. (see line 3 in my code) Line 3 (in my code) is creating new text files but it just puts  x_1 's variable into 90 new text files.

Comment: @AsenMartin You mean you want to put the data from file `files2(1)` into `X(A)_1.txt`, the data from file `files2(2)` into `X(A)_2.txt` and so on?

Comment: @AsenMartin By the way, I don't see how the code you posted avoids empty lines and I really don't know what you mean by "the files get rid of the second lines".

Comment: Exactly @Beaker, that's what I want . ''Put the data from file files2(1) into X(A)_1.txt, the data from file files2(2) into X(A)_2.txt and so on.'' Do you have any idea to make this code work. I think thirth and seventh line in code needs to change little bit.Thanks

Comment: @AsenMartin Where do you define `p`? I assume it's the same as the number of files in the directory?

Comment: Hi @Beaker, I noticed that the code is work incorrect. e.x; data from file files2(1) into X(A)_1.txt, the data from file files2(2) into X(A)_1.txt are not same. X(A)_1.txt this data copy into X(A)_80.txt and so on but it should be in order for example first  file variable should be copy into the new first file and second file variable should be in new second new file. Probably your code need one more line to fixe it. Could you help for that,thank you

Comment: @AsenMartin I'm sorry, but I'm really having an hard time understanding what you're saying. Can you please update your question with an example of exactly what you want? To me, "the data from file files2(2) into X(A)_1.txt` makes no sense because from what I understood you want all of the data from `files2(2)` to go into file `X(A)_2.txt` **only**.

Comment: Files2 include 90 files like X_1.txt,X_2.txt....X_90.txt. (These files are icludes variables, problem were blank lines for the files). With the code that you sent me, blank lines were gone for each files. Than these new files should be copy in new files (X(A)_1.txt,X(A)_2.txt,...,X(A)_90.txt). Also your code do this but the problem is that variable in files should be copy in order. X_1.txt variable to X(A)_1.txt, X_2.txt variable to X(A)_2.txt and so on. But the code  copy it in differently for example :X_1.txt variable to X(A)_80.txt

Comment: @AsenMartin I have no idea what you're trying to tell me. Why do you talk about blank lines again? I thought from your first comment that the problem with blank lines was solved. The code I gave copies the contents of `files2(1)` into `X(A)_1.txt` in exactly the same order as it appears in the file `files2(1)`. Please **edit your question** with a **small** example of the actual code you are using, the current output and your desired output.

Comment: @AsenMartin Can you replace `num2str(i)` in the third line with `regexp(files2(i).name, '([0-9]*)', 'match')`? Does that solve your issues?

Comment: @IKavanagh, Do you mean like this                                                         fidF = fopen(['beaminfo(A)_' regexp(files2(i).name, '([0-9]*)', 'match','.txt'], 'w');

Comment: @AsenMartin Yes, any luck?

Comment: ''Error using regexp
Invalid option for regexp: .txt.''
Its give the error @IKavanagh